# Efficiently looping over sub-arrays

Tags: performance, matlab

I have an array `A` with size `[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5] = size(A)`.

I have a custom function `myFunc` that I need to apply to each of the following subarrays of `A`:

```
B1 = A(:,1,:,:,:);
B2 = A(:,2,:,:,:);
B3 = A(:,3,:,:,:);
...
```

The function `myFunc` has signature:

```
function  [CN1,CN2,CN3,...] = myFunc(BN,varargin)
```

Here, `CN1`, `CN2`, `CN3`, etc, are a variable number of output arrays whose size depends only on the size of `BN`.

The goals is to calculate `CN1`, `CN2`, `CN3`, etc, for each `BN` and then create the arrays

```
D1 = cat(2,C11,C21,C31,...);
D2 = cat(2,C12,C22,C32,...);
D3 = cat(2,C13,C23,C33,...);
...
```

I wrote the following function to do this:

```
function varargout = testFunc(A,funcHdl,varargin)

% Extract the relevant dimensions for array A
sizeA = size(A);
d1 = sizeA(1);
d2 = sizeA(2);
otherDims = sizeA(3:end);

% Extract the number of output arguments of the function handle
numOut = nargout(funcHdl);
Cs = cell(d2,numOut);

% Get the output for all subarrays
for j=1:d2
    B = A(:,j,:);
    B = reshape(B,[d1,1,otherDims]);
    [Cs{j,:}] = funcHdl(B,varargin{:});
end

% Combined the outputs by concatenation
Ds = cell(1,numOut);
for n = 1:numOut
    Ds{1,n} = cat(2,Cs{:,n});
end

% Variable number of outputs
varargout = Ds;

end
```

It's not too inefficient, but I really need this procedure to be efficient. Am I missing a more efficient way of doing this, especially the concatenation?

I use Matlab2020a on Windows 10.

Comment: have you used *Run & Time* so that you can identify where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I used tic and toc to compare to a direct loop over the second dimension for `myFunc = @sum`, with preallocation. The direct loop is about 10% faster, but I can't really do it this way for my variable size arrays and variable number of outputs (or maybe I can actually? I'll rethink this). But I have not heard of Run & Time. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The bottlenecks are definitely the indexing and the function call in the first loop. They account for more than 80% of the runtime together. The concatenation is negligible. That was very helpful.

Comment: It might be completely irrelevant, but from the looks of it, you do not (or plan to) use this second dimension in a matrix type of way. If I am right, you might want to consider turning it into a cell array then you can have a cell array of matrices, i.e. something like `B = num2cell(A,[1,3,4,5])`, and then loop over `B`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, for structural reasons elsewhere in the code that I can't get into, I have to leave the second dimension there. In any case, I've now established that basically all the runtime is due to the indexing and function call, and I can't really change that. Besides, I've now compared to a previous implementation and at worse I lose a couple % in time. And for other reasons, it will enable me to save a lot in the function call itself. So my solution seems good enough now.